# Why does Sidekick not open my app anymore?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-sidekick

It's been about a year and little that I have used Sidekick in order to publish my NativeScript Android app. Everything worked fine in those days.

Now I updated Sidekick to 1.20.1-v.2020.6.3.2 (latest) accidently. Since then I can't open my app anymore.

I start Sidekick, click on [Open App], browse to my app's folder as usual and click on [Select Folder]. Error message: "Cannot find a valid app in D:...blabla. Do you want to remove the app from recent apps?".

What happened here? Do I have any chance to open my "old" app with this latest version of Sidekick?

Unfortunately I can't go back to a previous version of Sidekick because there are no download options for older versions any more. The only download I found is here [enter link description here](https://github.com/ProgressNS/sidekick-docs/wiki/Installation)

My app is based on NativeScript 7.2.1. Maybe that is the problem?

When I run "tns doctor" in the command propmpt I see that time has not stood still and we are on 8.0.x currently. But actually I do no dare upgrading from v7 to v8 because I am afraid this will break all different kinds of things as it used to do in the past. So, my best shot is to make Sidekick accept my v7 app.

I hope anybody can help me out. I am little lost, to be honest.

Thanks!
Ingmar

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a recent rollback point...

I dunno what to tell you, except save the file into a safe partition and try opening a copy of it on the latest version and see how bad it is. It might not break completely, you never know what "version deprication" has to offer, sometimes it's nothing, sometimes it's everything.

Without taking the plunge you won't know so... As we say on Sever development, back it up before you F**k it up :)

Comment: Hello Xyloz, thank you for your help. But I don't really see the relevance to my problem. "Save the file into a safe partition"??? In my original post I was not talking about a single file. I can not open a whole project due to ... well, I don't know. I either need access to an older version of NS Sidekick (which does not seem to be available anymore) or I need an idea on how to open my existing project with the latest NS Sidekick.

Comment: A profect is contained in a file, and your system, the one you accidentally updated to the new version of Sidekick, can it be rolled back to before you updated it!

Comment: Sorry, still not sure what you are talking about. What is a "profect"? Are you referring to something that is specific to my problem? Or are you thinking of something that is related to backups/restore points in general?

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, then this will not help. Thank you though!